# Reference a job scope java bean in xml configuration

Tags: xml, spring, spring-batch, spring-java-config

In my project, I mix Spring Javaconfig and XML config, which I only use due to the convenient batch namespace Spring has.  In xml configuration, I refer to a @JobScope listener like so

```
<step abstract="true" id="hist">
    <listeners>
        <listener ref="histListener"/>
    </listeners>
</step>
```

This listener is defined as a Javaconfig @Bean

```
@Bean
@JobScope
public HistListener histListener(@Value("#{jobParameters[inputFilePath]}") String inputFilePath) {
  return new HistListener(inputFilePath);
}
```

Problem is that when the XML is parsed, it expects to call the proxy bean *histListener* constructor with no parameters, even though it requires the *inputFilePath* parameter injected by the job scope @Value annotation.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy216 cannot be cast to org.springframework.batch.core.listener.StepExecutionListenerSupport
    at org.springframework.batch.core.listener.StepExecutionListenerSupport$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c521b3f5.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at sdc.service.injection.springbatch.listener.HistListener$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$24a84ea5.beforeStep(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.listener.CompositeStepExecutionListener.beforeStep(CompositeStepExecutionListener.java:77)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:194)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:386)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:135)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:304)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:128)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at $Proxy86.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've been able to convert the @Bean to its XML equivalent without any problem, but it seems that in this case, XML and JavaConfig do not get along.  Has anyone found a solution to this ?

Comment: Could elaborate a bit on how both configuration types are related here? @Import? where are located component scan directives? Basically, what is importing what. Thanks!

Comment: Does `HistListener` extend `StepExecutionListenerSupport`?

Comment: To make this clearer, I've made a test project [here](https://github.com/thebignet/stackoverflow-springBatchXmlAndJavaConfig).  [Diff](https://github.com/thebignet/stackoverflow-springBatchXmlAndJavaConfig/compare/working...failing) between branch **working** and **failing** show that the reader with jobscope has been removed from XML configuration and added as a Bean in javaconfig in the same way, meaning that it has a JobScope annotation and is passed a @Value parameter like it was done in XML configuration.